# Convert project from Spring framework to Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a set of projects in Spring framework and I have to Find the ones which can be converted to Spring boot.
Is there anything that is related to Spring framework and cannot be converted to spring boot ? In my research, I Could not Find something like that.
But does anyone know something, like a dependency, which would force the project to stay in Spring framework ?

Answer (score 0):

**Spring Boot uses the Spring Framework as a foundation** and improvises on it. It simplifies Spring dependencies and runs applications straight from a command line. Spring Boot provides several features to help manage enterprise applications easily. **Spring Boot is not a replacement for the Spring, but it’s a tool for working faster and easier on Spring applications.** It simplifies much of the architecture by adding a layer that helps automate configuration and deployment while making it easier to add new features.

Most of the changes for migrating Spring Framework application to Spring Boot are related to configurations.This migration will have minimal impact on the application code or other custom components.Spring Boot brings a number of advantages to the development.

1. It simplifies Spring dependencies by taking the opinionated view.
2. Spring Boot provides a preconfigured set of technologies/framework to reduces error-prone configuration so we as a developer focused on building our business logic and not thinking of project setup.
3. You really don’t need those big XML configurations for your project.
4. Embed Tomcat, Jetty or Undertow directly.
5. Provide opinionated Maven POM to simplify your configurations.
6. Application metrics and health check using actuator module.
7. Externalization of the configuration files.

Good to refer this for **migrating from Spring to Spring Boot** application: https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-boot/migrating-from-spring-to-spring-boot/